# Convert xls to xlsx with Apple Script

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I have some *.xls files in the same folder. How to convert those files into .xlsx with Apple Script.

'/Users/me/Desktop/data/' here is where the xls files stored. I want to store the xlsx files in another folder.

Thank you very much!